# How to set the default button of a MessageDialog in QML?

Tags: button, qml, messagedialog

The default button is "Yes", but I want to set the button "No" as the default button.

How to do it?

Comment: show us your code,,,help us to help you...

Comment: I think this is one case where code isn't really necessary, as long as you're moderately familiar with the framework and its terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any way to achieve this through the current `MessageDialog` API, but I'd also imagine that this is very much platform-specific, and that's why it's hidden.

You can make your own dialog, though:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    width: 500
    height: 500
    visible: true

    Dialog {
        id: dialog
        visible: true

        contentItem: FocusScope {
            Row {
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.right: parent.right

                Button {
                    text: "No"
                    isDefault: true
                    focus: true
                    onClicked: dialog.close()
                }
                Button {
                    text: "Yes"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: dialog]

Comment: Thank you for stopping me going on looking for the solution. I have spent so much time on it.